# MLE of $\theta$ when $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d with pdf $f(x)=\frac{2(\theta-x)}{\theta^2}\mathbf1_{0<x<\theta}$

Tags: self-study, distributions, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with pdf

$$f(x\mid\theta)=\begin{cases}\frac{2(\theta-x)}{\theta^2}&,\text{ if }0<x<\theta \\ 0 &,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

What is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ ?

I know how to find MLE of uniform and exponential functions like maximising log likelihood etc. But I am unable to figure out the mle in the above case.

Comment: The answers in these threads might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371207/maximum-likelihood-estimate-for-a-likelihood-defined-by-parts, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/mle-for-triangle-distribution/64103

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am not getting a closed form of mle.

Comment: The likelihood function $L(\theta; x_1, x_2, x_n)$ is given by
$$L(\theta) = \begin{cases}0, & \theta \leq x_\max,\\ \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2(\theta-x_i)}{\theta^2}, & \theta > x_\max,\end{cases}$$ where $x_\max = \max_i x_i$, and thus jumps from $0$ to a nonzero value at $x_\max$.  I suspect that $L(\theta)$ is a decreasing function of  $\theta$ for $\theta \in (x_\max, \infty)$  so that the MLE will be $x_\max$; at least, that's the way it happens for _discrete_ random variables whose pmfs are monotone decreasing functions on $(0,\theta)$.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate How can it be shown analytically that the likelihood is decreasing in $\theta $?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/345874/119261

Comment: MLE is not the maximum. Look at a particular case: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/317874/119261.

Comment: Thanks @StubbornAtom